# Difference between #+filetags and #+categories

Tags: org-roam

I am using `orgroam` as a [Zettelkasten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zettelkasten) and partly as a personal wiki. I do not use TODO-Lists, Agenda or something else.

Currently I use round about 4 different filetags, not more. I use them to specify the type of the node but not the type of its content (e.g. topics). With categories I have no experiences yet.

In the context of using OrgRoam as Zettelkasten (or "second brain") what is the difference between `#+filetags:` and `#+categories:`? What are there implications when using OrgRoam and creating and searching for nodes?

Comment: Good question. I think the answer is indeed not as well-defined as most things in Org. Roughly (and with no reference to OrgRoam, which I do not use, apologies), I think categories are intended as file-level and/or subtree-level metadata, and tags are intended as subtree-level and/or headline-level metadata. I assume that OrgRoam cannot substantially change these semantics; apologies if that assumption is incorrect.

Comment: I agree with @Phil Hudson: categories seem  to be coarser labels whereas tags are finer. IMO, tags are much more flexible and Org mode provides facilities to use them (e.g. for searching) that add to that flexibility. Whether OrgRoam tilts the calculus differently, I don't know: like Phil, I don't use it - but my impression is that it uses links for its operations, so tags and/or categories are extras.

Comment: One other difference between tags and categories: directly or by inheritance each headline can have either zero or one category, but zero, one or many tags.